# Refill HPs on the map possible?

Tags: a-dark-room

Can I refill my HPs on the map - not in battle? I sometimes have battles that leave me with very little hitpoints, but it seams I can only refill them when in battle. Is it possible to do this on the map (like in the houses where water gets refilled?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your health can be restored in only two ways:

1. Automatically, when you return home to the village
2. Manually, when you consume cured meat during combat
3. (Edit) Manually, when you consume medicine during combat [browser version only]

This forces you to employ some strategy when out in the world.

For example, if your cured meat cool down is about to finish, you might wait a second before landing the finishing blow on an enemy just so you can get a heal off before ending that combat sequence.

You might also move your character back to the middle parts of the map and try to trigger a fight with a much easier enemy, who doesn't hit nearly as hard, so that you can bump up your health while they try to kill you.

Interestingly, the Dark Room Wiki lists "[Medicine](http://adarkroom.wikia.com/wiki/Resources#Medicine)" as an obtainable item; however, it lists this only for the Browser version of the game and not the mobile version. I've played the browser version only a few times and have never seen this.

**Edit:**
After studying the [game's code for the browser version](https://github.com/doublespeakgames/adarkroom), I see that medicine is indeed a consumable. It can be traded for in the shop and can also be dropped by some enemies including snipers and soldiers. When you have medicine on you, you'll get a new button option in the UI during combat to heal yourself with it.